# Building a shelf question, weight bearing advice needed

Tags: wood, woodworking

If I were to take a bunch of 1x2's, say 13, and glue them face to face to reach a desired shelf depth of 9.75" (plus a 1/2" nicer wood facing to reach my total depth needed of 10.25"), a length of 6' and then properly supported with 4 steel brackets screwed into wall studs, would that support about 85 to 90 lbs. of record albums?  Asking for a blog project of mine.  Thank you!

Comment: Use good quality wood glue and clamps to keep the glue joints tight until the glue dries.

Comment: Tip: as you glue each new ply, put a few screws in. (countersink and counterbore the top one so the screw doesn't catch.) If there's inconsistency in the wood, you can push/pull to get them near perfect. Plus, you won't have the whole stack squirming around in the clamps.

Answer (score 1):

That glued-up board will comfortably support an evenly distributed load of that weight.